# Which properties are stored in which object in Javascript prototyping?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, chain

```
class Message {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.text;
  }
}

class ErrorMessage extends Message {
  constructor(text, code) {
    super(text);
    this.code = code;
  }
}
```

`const message = new ErrorMessage('Test', 404);`

What exactly is prototype, let's say if we call: ErrorMessage.prototype or Message.prototype?
Which properties are stored in which objects (text, toString and code)?

Answer (score 2):

Both constructors, when run, have a `this` which is the new instance being constructed. So, the lines

```
this.text = text;
```

and

```
this.code = code;
```

both put a property directly on the instance.

You can see this if you check `hasOwnProperty`:

```js
class Message {
  constructor(text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.text;
  }
}

class ErrorMessage extends Message {
  constructor(text, code) {
    super(text);
    this.code = code;
  }
}

const m = new ErrorMessage();
console.log(
  m.hasOwnProperty('text'),
  m.hasOwnProperty('code')
);
```

`toString` is a normal method on `Message.prototype`. This means that the instance (assuming you're creating an `ErrorMessage`) inherits this property via `ErrorMessage.prototype`, since *it* inherits from `Message.prototype`. The internal prototype chain is:

```
instance <- ErrorMessage.prototype <- Message.prototype <- Object.prototype
```